# AS3 Camera input gets distorted when exported to AIR

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, webcam

I've built an AIR application with flash/as3 that has a webcam display on the stage. While building the app, and in all my tests everything looks and works just dandy, but when I publish for AIR the image gets stretched. The bounds of the image seem to stay the same, but the actual cam output is what's distorted. Has anyone come into this problem before?

I should add, this is a desktop app, which is permanently installed on one machine, so device compatibility should not be an issue.

this is the camera setup:

```
    var cam:Camera = Camera.getCamera();
    cam.setMode(280,380,20);
    var video:Video = new Video(380,380);
```

this is where i first call the camera...

```
    video.attachCamera(cam);
    video.x = 355;
    video.scaleX = -1;
    video.y = -100;
    addChildAt(video, 0);
```

the reason for the odd sizing, is that it sits behind a frame, that changes positions throughout the interactive.

Comment: Could really do with some source code to look at, otherwise its all guess work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not necessarily the answer you are looking for, but you should keep this in mind:

You are asking the camera to capture at the resolution of 280 x 380, which is not a standard 4:3 aspect ratio.

When you call `cam.setMode(280,380,20);` the docs say that Flash will try to set the cameras resolution to your specifications, and if the camera does not support that resolution it will try to find one that matches. So you may or may not be getting this actual resolution.

`setMode()` has a fourth parameter, which can disable this functionality. Read the [docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Camera.html#setMode%28%29) on that so you understand the implications :)

Then you display the video in a Video object that is 380x380. So I would expect the image to be stretched in the horizontal direction (b/c the original source is only 280).

It's not clear why this behaves differently: are you saying that running the debug version of the app works, but when you export the release build and run that it looks funky?

Finally, what is `scaleX = -1` doing? I recall this as some sort of nifty trick I used in the past... but it's purpose here is escaping me :)

Comment: When debugging it essentially crops the video, which is what I want, but when I build, it squashes it all in frame. I will check the setMode parameters...!  the scaleX = -1 essentially just flips the vid so its mirrored. the disadvantage to this, is that it flips the registration point, because it is technically scaling it backwards, so it's wise to do this before any coords are set, so you're not stuck moving all your values around after you flop your registration. (this could be fixed later with an offset, but thats another mess to deal with!) ....

Comment: I recently implemented a cropping solution for a Video object, to do that I wrapped a `Video` object in a `Sprite` then used the `scrollRect` property on the `Sprite` object and gave it a `Rect` who's x/y/width/height specified the visible area of the video. I wouldn't expect it to crop at all by resizing things (ie: it seems like the behavior in debug mode is wrong). Thanks for explaining `scaleX=-1` -- that *is* a nifty trick!

Comment: of course! thats a swell idea...! I think I'll jump on that as opposed to playing with these pesky camera objects anymore. thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Yep, source code would be cool. Btw, i suggest you, as soon as you get the video streaming running, to set by hand the video.width and video.height property.
This will force the cam to display at the correct size.